# angular2 using method of another component

Tags: angular

I have components in hierarhy: app.component > intro.component > header.component. I want to use in header.component, method that is defined in app.component. I recognize there's way to make it with @viewChild. What's easest way to make it work?

//edit
I want to do (click) event on html tag that is in header.component.html. In this function I want to run method from app.component.

Comment: You are in right direction. You should use @ViewChild decorator.

Comment: What do you mean by a method 'initialized' in app.component? Are you asking about how to call a method defined in app.component in header.component or vice versa? Or is it about a 'property' initialized in app.component to be passed to the header.component?

Comment: I meant that method is defined. U updated post, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass callback function to child component as @input (React style):

```js
 //app.component.html:

 <app-intro [appMethod] = "boundMethod"></app-intro>

 export class AppComponent { 

     ngOnInit() {
                this.boundMethod = this.appMethod.bind(this);
     }

     appMethod() {
                console.log("appMethod called");
     }
 }


 //intro.component:

 <app-header [appMethod] = "appMethod"></app-header>

 export class IntroComponent {
     @Input() public appMethod: Function; 
 }

 //header.component:

 export class HeaderComponent {
     @Input() appMethod: Function; 
     ngOnInit() {
                appMethod(); // Call parent method 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible example:

In the html in app.component.html:

```
...<app-intro></app-intro>
```

the html in intro.compoennt.html:

```
...<app-header #header></app-header>
```

and in app.component.ts:

```
@ContentChild("header")
public headerComponent: HeaderComponent;
```

Check https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild

Comment: another possible scenario is that you use a service which you can inject into any control to pass around objects.

Comment: Why declare @ViewChild("header") private headerComponent: HeaderComponent; in app.component when i want to run method in header.component?

Comment: Sorry, yep, that is a problem: you must declare it as public, if you want it to use outside it's control.

Comment: Also, I checked, and there is a slight difference between '@ViewChild and  '@ContentChild: check it [here](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e). If it is not the direct child in the template, you will not see it with  '@ViewChild, but  '@ContentChild will "scan" the DOM. I updated the answer